# How to combine, in a PDF document, a tooltip with a hyperref : xspace behavior broken

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdf, pdfcomment, xspace

Acronyms in my PDF document should provide a tooltip definition, as well as a hyperref to where each was defined in the text.

The following document uses xspace and stacks a tooltip with a hyperref, to give needed context for an acronym.  As you can see, at least in Evince viewer, both the tooltip and a preview of the hyperref location come up. That's pretty neat. However, xspace is not working properly! I get spaces where there should not be any. I need to fix the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}  % Compile with pdflatex
\usepackage[allcolors=blue,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\FVR{\pdftooltip{\hyperref[acronym:FVR]{FVR}\xspace}{Focal Value Rounding (See page \pageref{acronym:FVR})}}

\section{Intro}
Here's where we define
``\textbf{focal value rounding}'' (\textbf{FVR}\label{acronym:FVR}) behavior.

\section{Main}

This sentence with \FVR and \FVR, has extra spaces before punctuation \FVR.

\end{document}
```

Here's the output, with the mouse hovering over one of the FVR links:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xspace` package documentation](http://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/xspace.pdf) says that `\xspace` is supposed to be used at the end of a macro. Simply moving the `\xspace` to the end of your definition seems to do the trick:

```latex
\newcommand{\FVR}{\pdftooltip{\hyperref[acronym:FVR]{FVR}}{Focal Value Rounding (See page \pageref{acronym:FVR})}\xspace}
```

[image: MWE with fixed \xspace]